# Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно составить регулярное выражение

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Всем добрый день! Пытался регулярными выражениями решить проблему с отображением формул, теперь есть две проблемы :)
Суть вопроса: когда после формулы в mathjax следует запятая, точка, точка с запятой или иной знак препинания, то такой знак нередко переносится на новую строку, что смотрится отвратительно. Чтобы избежать этого, нужно заключить формулу и следующий за нею знак препинания в `<span>` типа такого: `<span>\( тут код формулы \),<span>`. Здесь знаки `\(` и `\)` обрамляют формулу для последующего рендеринга mathjax.

Я попробовал решить эту проблему (для начала - хотя бы с точкой после формулы) перед выдачей страницы пользователю следующим образом - найти все вхождения структуры `<math>формула</math>.` в полученном из базы данных тексте параграфа и преобразовать в `<span>\( формула \).<span>`:

```php
$text = 'Тут формула с точкой: <math>f1</math>. А тут с запятой: <math>f2</math>, а тут опять с точкой: <math>f3</math>. Эта с запятой: <math>f3</math>, далее просто текст ';

$text = preg_replace('|<math>(.*)(<\/math>\.)|Uis', '<span>\( $1 \).</span>', $text);
```

Результат, к сожалению, был удручающим:

```
Тут формула с точкой: <span>\( f1 \).</span> А тут с запятой: <span>\( f2</math>, а тут опять с точкой: <math>f3 \).</span> Эта с запятой: <math>f3</math>, далее просто текст
```

Первое вхождение было заменено, а далее - регулярное выражение захватило слишком большой кусок. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать так, чтобы если после куска `<math>text</math>` не было знака препинания, программа просто переходила бы к следующему куску?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По-моему, тут дело в захвате точки или запятой после `</math>`.
Попробуйте такие выражения для поиска и замены:

```
$text = 'Тут формула с точкой: <math>f1</math>. А тут с запятой: <math>f2</math>, а тут опять с точкой: <math>f3</math>. Эта с запятой: <math>f3</math>, далее просто текст ';
$text = preg_replace('/<math>(.*)<\/math>(\.|,)/Uis', '<span>\( $1 \)$2</span>', $text);
echo $text;
```

Вывод:

```
Тут формула с точкой: <span>\( f1 \).</span> А тут с запятой: <span>\( f2 \),</span> а тут опять с точкой: <span>\( f3 \).</span> Эта с запятой: <span>\( f3 \),</span> далее просто текст
```

В первую группу захвата помещаем формулу между тегами `math`, а во вторую - найденную точку или запятую после тэга `math`. При замене первую группу оборачиваем в скобки, после скобок вставляем найденную точку или запятую из второй группы захвата.

[Демо](https://regex101.com/r/SnTztz/1)